# FragmentActivity and Fragment ... how do I work in this scenario?

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-fragmentactivity

I couldn't really think of a good question title. Sorry about that.

Here's my problem:
I have my main activity:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

    namespace AndroidApplication2
    {
        [Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
        public class Activity1 : FragmentActivity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);          
                //Not sure if I need the code below
                FragmentTransaction ft = this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                Activity2 fragment = new Activity2();
                ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
                ft.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

The XML file for the main activity looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        class="AndroidApplication2.Activity2"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the Activity2 looks like this:

```
namespace AndroidApplication2
{
    [Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
    public class Activity2 : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater p0, ViewGroup p1, Bundle p2)
        {
            return p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout, p1, false);
        }
    }
}
```

and the fragment_layout.axml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a TextView from the fragment" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a Button from the fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code is in C# using Xamarin.

Now, all I want to do is, access the button in fragment_layout and use that to replace the fragment in Activity1(my main activity). I am using this to avoid creating new activities for every simple thing, like showing details of something but I cannot use any popups as well.

I am not able to access the button on the fragment that I loaded in my main FragmentActivity with which I can replace it with another fragment. Help! Thanks! Any other improvements or suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Alright, one of my problem is solved. I cannot replace the fragment if it is added statically. But I still don't know how to access the buttons of the new fragment that I added. Please help me with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the button by inflating the view first, then return it.
For example:

```
View view = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout, p1, false);

// now we can access button, textview etc... in the layout

_btnAboutUs = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnAboutUs);

return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

"But I still don't know how to access the buttons of the new fragment that I added."

Well you can always reference that button like this:

```
_btnAboutUs = (Button)FindViewById (Resource.Id.btnAboutUs);
```

But perhaps using a button inside a fragment, to replace the fragment the button itself is in, is not the best way to go.
Why not put the button in Activity1 so you can use it's fragmentManager to replace the fragment. A fragment does not have a fragmentManager, but an activity does.